# Why does eroding / dilating image with zeros structuring element cause (-)Inf value?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I use imerode and imdilate in matlab with image m

```
0 0 0 
0 1 0
0 0 0
```

and structuring element f

```
0
```

the result for using imerode is

```
inf inf inf
inf inf inf
inf inf inf
```

and for imdilate is

```
-inf -inf -inf
-inf -inf -inf
-inf -inf -inf
```

Can someone explain it to me?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This artifact happens when applying the structuring element on a non-existent value (for example, it may occur at the borders, or in your case by using a 1x1 structuring element that excludes the center).

In such cases, MATLAB's `imerode` and `imdilate` yield `-Inf` and `Inf`, respectively.

You can read more [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2007/03/23/pad-values-in-dilation-and-erosion/) for a clarification of this phenomenon.

Comment: Calm down there, this is completely wrong. His structuring element includes the center, and if it was correctly specified then it would simply output the input image both for erosion and dilation.

Comment: @mmgp No. a structuring element of `f = 1` would have yielded the input image as the output. A structuring element of 0 does _not_ include the center in any way. Sorry, I'll have to give you a -1, I think your answer is blatantly misleading.

Comment: Please, learn about non-flat and flat morphology before continuing on this.

Comment: @mmgp Non-flat structuring elements have nothing to do with this question; the OP is describing a flat empty structuring element with no neighbors. While not very useful, it is legal, and the output is perfectly defined. You, on the other hand, are trying to force an explanation with a structuring element with 1 neighbor using `strel('arbitrary', 1)`, which is simply a distraction.

Comment: way to miss the point. Non-flat and flat structuring elements have all to do with this question because the OP is unaware of how `strel` works and so are you. A flat structuring element is always `0` everywhere, but it have to have some neighborhood to be applied. In Matlab, the notion of neighborhood is defined by another matrix, with `1`s and `0`s. Please, check the basic definitions of erosion and dilation for both cases. This is an insult to mathematical morphology. Matlab may have confused you too, but that is not a reason to not accept that your answer is wrong.

Comment: @mmgp _"A flat structuring element is always 0 everywhere"_ -- you should be getting another -1 for this. Please re-read the documentation for `strel`.

Comment: You are confusing neighborhood with shape, and it is sad that you still don't know the basic equations for erosion/dilation for flat and non-flat elements. You chose to not learn it, there is nothing else I can do for you but I will say it once more. A flat SE is 0 everywhere, because that is a flat shape, and nothing else makes sense for a SE that can be represented as a set of displacements. But, it has to have some neighborhood to be applied and in Matlab this neighborhood is defined as a matrix of `0`s and `1`s. And this neighborhood can be exactly the same for non-flat, with another shape

Comment: Trust me, I'm not confusing anything. I'm perfectly familiar with mathematical morphology, and this discussion is pointless. The only thing left for me is to urge you to re-read the [representation of structural elements in **MATLAB**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/morphology-fundamentals-dilation-and-erosion.html#f18-22581), especially the part about flat SEs, and then re-evaluate your argument. Good luck.

Comment: You are very far from being familiar with MM, there is no reason to trust you on this matter. What you are seeing is simply the neighborhood of the SE, not its shape. Please, create a SE in matlab as in: `se = steel('square', 3)`. Then check its neighborhood, `se.getnhood`, and also its shape (or height as denominated in Matlab), `se.getheight`.

Comment: @mmgp I suggest you do the same for `strel('diamond', 3)`. It is the neighborhood that assumes the diamond shape, not the height. You should review the link about SE representation in MATLAB in my previous comment.

Comment: No.. the neighborhood defines the set of displacements to be used, this just happens to be how Matlab defines it. Now, you chose to ignore its shape again, didn't you ? Check what `se.getheight` returns for your diamond. Check what it returns for any flat SE.

Comment: @mmgp The height matrix is the same for a flat diamond and a flat square. Are you suggesting that their shape is also the same? Read the link. Nothing more to say, this is getting nowhere.

Comment: Yes, their shape is the same: it is a flat shape. Any flat SE has a certain region of support, and it can always be represented as zeros. Matlab separates this in two parts, neighborhood and height. You are just confused with Matlab representation and how it reflects on the actual equations of erosion and dilation. You are ignoring the part where your MM "knowledge" is limited to flat morphology and also to the way Matlab choses to represents flat elements. There is a world outside of that, but it needs courage to assume that you are wrong.

Comment: Your comments are supercilious and this is noise. Good day to you.

Comment: I went that mode since you ignored everything I said, while assuming what you said is correct above all.

Comment: This answer does not address the issue at all. This has nothing to do with the padding of the image (which is only a Matlab implementation detail that should have never even matter in the first place). The most simple way to show that the answer is wrong is to consider the centre element of the image where dilation or erosion would not have been affected by the padding at all. Actually, none of the image pixels will be affected by the padding since the SE is of size 1x1.

Comment: @carandraug I think implementation matters. In simple words, when performing erosion, MATLAB computes a minimum for each group of pixels defined by the structuring element. While doing so, it replaces "missing" values with a constant value `-Inf`, which is guaranteed to be less or equal to all image pixels. The same goes for dilation, only with `Inf`. When your SE is of size 1x1 and excludes the center itself, you're left with the "missing" value alone. Perhaps I should rephrase the answer and say "replace missing values" instead of "pad outside the image" to clarify?

Comment: Implementation should not matter since these are mathematical operations. I don't know what their definition for an empty neighbourhood though. So we are discussing Matlab implementation instead of the real mathematics :( But it's still not about missing values (there are none). It's about computing the max/min values of an empty set, and the implementation details of the starting value for that (at least I think so since Matlab is closed source). Your answer and the link to the Mathworks blog are about padding with `Inf` --- which is about performance when dealing with border elements.

Comment: Seems that with certain definitions of dilation and erosion, an answer of `-Inf` and `+Inf` are mathematically correct and not an artifact of the implementation. Took me a while to work it out. Check my answer and please give me any feedback.

Comment: @carandraug First of all the original question is about the fact that there are `Inf` values in the resulting image. So saying that this is an artifact of implementation is a perfectly legitimate answer (it being correct or not is another issue). Regarding the link I gave, would you agree that it explains the same phenomenon for a different use case?
Looks like your answer extends mine, and perhaps clarifies the result more elaborately.

Comment: @carandraug Anyway, thank you for commenting about my answer. I've decided to rephrase it a little to make it more accurate.

Comment: No. The original question is *not* "about the fact that there are `Inf` values in the resulting image". The question is about *that*, happening "with zeros structing element". The result is the same but the reasons are completely different.

Comment: @carandraug you are interpreting the question to fit your answer. It's debatable, but let's not clutter the comment section about it anymore because it's pointless.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111540/discussion-between-carandraug-and-eitan-t).

Answer (score 1):

To understand the issue, one needs to under the erosion and dilation operators. The typical generalization of those operations is as a local minimum and maximum filters (where the structuring element (SE), or kernel, selects the elements to filter).

## Explaining dilation and erosion with real examples

With a SE that is a 3x3 square of true elements, erosion computes the minimum of each image element by finding the minimum between that element and all of its 8 neighbours:

```
octave> im
im =

   5   9   2   6
   8   5   8   1
   7   8   6   9
   8   4   8   1

octave> imerode (im, [1 1 1; 1 1 1; 1 1 1])
ans =

   5   2   1   1
   5   2   1   1
   4   4   1   1
   4   4   1   1
```

And if you set the centre element of the SE to false, then it computes the minimum of all its 8 neighbours elements (note that it does not include itself).

```
octave> imerode (im, [1 1 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 1])
ans =

   5   2   1   1
   5   2   1   2
   4   4   1   1
   4   6   1   6
```

But what happens when your SE is "empty" and has no true elements? What if there are no elements from the image from where to compute the minimum? Your use case, a SE of just `0`, is very specific in that it does not have any true element at all. The erosion operation needs to compute the minimum of an empty set. What is the minimum value of an empty set?

```
octave> imerode (im, [0])
ans =

   Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf
   Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf
   Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf
   Inf   Inf   Inf   Inf
```

The answer does not make a lot of sense. But neither does the operation, i.e., the minimum of an empty set. But how does Matlab actually gets to this odd answer of `Inf`?

## How you get the maybe wrong answer?

The results of `Inf` and `-Inf` (which also happens in Octave) is an implementation detail. Since Matlab is closed-source we can't know for sure how they get there but here's pseudo-code for a possible case (it similar in principal to what happens in Octave):

```
## pseudo-code for imerode (local-minimum) that may causes this issue
set eroded to image
for each element in image
    set MIN_VAL to +Inf
    for each value in element neighbourhood
        if value < MIN_VAL
            set MIN_VAL to value
    set eroded[element index] to MIN_VAL
```

## Is this really all? Can we really not compute the erosion and dilation with such SE?

If one looks into theoretical treatises defining this operations, usually in the continuous interval (instead of discrete), you will find that instead of maximum and minimum it refers to [supremum and infimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum) whose result is [`-Inf` and `+Inf` for empty sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set#Extended_real_numbers). So it depends if you use supremum and infimum, instead of maximum and minimum, in your definition of dilation and erosion. And It also depends if you accept that the supremum and infimum of an empty set are `-Inf` and `+Inf`.

Does Matlab return `Inf` and `-Inf` on purpose because of this? I don't know but I will no. Their documentation of imerode and imdilate only make reference to max and min operations and the most obvious implementation (see pseudo-code above) leads to this results.

I know that I was not aware of this when I implemented `imdilate` and `imerode` for Octave some years ago.

## What about this other answer and comments about padding value?

If your image does not have values of `Inf`, there are two ways for them to appear as result of `imdilate` and `imerode`. The end result, `Inf` values, may look the same but the reasons how you get them are completely different.

One situation, the one that this question is about, is when you have a "blank" SE, i.e., a SE with no true elements. In that case, at each point of your image you compute the min of an empty set. This has nothing to do with padding. There is no padding and no missing value whatsoever. The reason why you get an `Inf` is that you don't *really* generate the whole set of values and then find its min. You start from one value (`Inf`, the largest possible) and then compare with the next value that would have been in that set. Because that set would have been empty, a comparison is never made, and end up with that initial value of `Inf`.  It explains this:

```
octave> imerode (5, 0)
ans = Inf
```

The other case, which leads to the same result but has nothing to do with the question, is when a SE only "picks" elements outside the image.  This is explained in the Mathworks blog [Pad values in dilation and erosion](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2007/03/23/pad-values-in-dilation-and-erosion/). In theory, erosion and dilation operations ignore out of border elements (they should not even exist). In practice, you do count them because ignoring them is computationally expensive (since then you need to know where in the image you are and adjust the SE accordingly).  For example, if your SE is a 3x3 square, and you are evaluating the top left corner of your image, it's difficult to avoid the top and left out-of-border image elements. So Matlab pads the image with `Inf` because those values will not affect the result of min.  But that is only true when there are other values on the set to pick the min from. If at any point in the image all of the SE is out-of-border elements, then you will compute the min of a set of `Inf`s that came from the padding only.  It explains this:

```
octave> imerode (5, [1 1 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 1])
ans = Inf

octave> imerode (zeros (3), [0 0 0; 1 0 0; 1 1 0])
ans =

     0     0     0
     0     0     0
   Inf     0     0

octave> imerode (zeros (3), [0 0 0; 0 0 0; 1 1 1])
ans =

     0     0     0
     0     0     0
   Inf   Inf   Inf
```

Comment: @EitanT, It does contradict your answer.  I edited the section with the triangle SE example into a comparison between the two answers.  The only thing you got right is the "empty set" part (which you did not had before) but then you address all the wrong reasons to get it.  It has nothing to do about padding (which was your original answer and the link), and it has nothing to do about excluding the centre (which you added now). It is about having an empty SE to start with. In the end, they cover very different issues.

Comment: Applying a 1x1 SE that excludes the center forces MATLAB to calculate the minimum of non-existent values (an empty set) just like applying that SE outside the boundaries of the image (a missing set). In both cases the logic to handle such cases is to pad the resulting set with an `Inf` value. We can agree on disagreeing, but let's stop here because obviously we're not making progress.

Comment: @EitanT but that's exactly where you are wrong. "In both cases the logic to handle such cases is to pad the resulting set [...]". There is no padding whatsoever in the first case. When you have a 1x1 SE, there is no padding. And the question is about a 1x1 SE.

Comment: Please refer to [what I mentioned in the chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111540/discussion-between-carandraug-and-eitan-t)

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not have a structuring element (SE) equivalent to `0` if that is the output you get. According to your other question [Erose/Dilate image with zeros structuring element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111491/erose-dilate-image-with-zeros-structuring-element/14114379#14114379), this is merely a misuse of the `strel` function from Matlab.

First, let us suppose you have in fact a SE that is an unique point `0`. For erosion that means you will take the minimum value between the intensity at current position under inspection and only itself, so there is nothing else to output than the intensity at the current position. This is the same for dilation. To check that, verify any correct text that describes the formulas for erosion and dilation. And, in Matlab:

```
f = [0 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 0]
se = strel('arbitrary', 1, 0)
imerode(f, se)

ans =

     0     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     0

imdilate(f, se)

ans =

     0     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     0
```

Now, if you create an invalid SE as in `se = strel('arbitrary', 0)` and try to use morphological operators with it, I can only expect undefined results. Matlab is being nice and giving you something to look at.