# Erose/Dilate image with zeros structuring element

Tags: image-processing, mathematical-morphology

If I have a structuring element looks like this one (the origin is at the center of SE):

```
0  0  0
0  0  0 
0  0  0
```

If I perform the erosion/dilation on an binary image, the result turns out all 0 or 1. 
Can someone please explain this one to me? (Check by matlab)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a perfectly valid SE. It is a flat square, commonly accepted and available in every image processing library.

Now, it is important to understand the difference and similarity between flat and non-flat structuring elements (or structuring functions). The similarity is that they operate over a certain neighborhood. For an elementar square element, the neighborhood can be represented by a 3x3 matrix where every element is in the neighborhood of the element (for a rhombus SE, for example, it would be a 3x3 matrix too but the corners wouldn't belong to the neighborhood). In Matlab, this specific neighborhood relation is expressed by `ones(3, 3)` or simply `[1 1 1; 1 1 1; 1 1 1]`. The difference between flat and non-flat SE is what makes the `strel` function in Matlab be the way it is. A non-flat SE implies that it can treat neighbors differently, so it doesn't rely exclusively on the value 0 (the definitions of erosion and dilation are slightly modified to handle this situation). As an example, the square SE is correctly defined in Matlab as `strel('arbitrary', ones(3, 3), zeros(3, 3))` (specifying `zeros(3, 3)` as the second parameter is basically an error, since you are saying you have no neighbors then). On the other hand, a non-flat square can be defined in infinite ways, one of them could be `strel('arbitrary', ones(3, 3), [-1 -1 -1; -1 0 -1; -1 -1 -1])`.

Summing up, you are most likely using `strel` incorrectly.