# Erosion/Dilation image with structuring element that contains only origin?

Tags: image-processing, mathematical-morphology

Is that true if we erode / dilate image with a structuring element that contains only the origin, the result will be the same as the original image ?

Comment: Yes when the SE is flat, write the equations for erosion/dilation and you will see that. Review your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110820/why-does-eroding-dilating-image-with-zeros-structuring-element-cause-inf-va which is basically a duplicate of this after the SE is created correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mathematical Morphology there are flat and non-flat structuring elements, but since people usually refer to the first (sometimes without knowing it), I'm assuming your question is about flat SE. With this assumption, the question to your answer is: yes. To see why is that, let us consider the equations for erosion and dilation, respectively, for an input function `f` with a flat and symmetric SE `S`:

[image]                     [image]

There are many ways to define erosion and dilation, but for this time consider these ones above. If it was not clear before, now you can see what it means to erode and dilate with a flat element. Consider a position `x` in your 2D image `f`, let's say your image has 300 columns and 300 rows, so, for example, `x` could be `(10, 10)`, `(3, 2)`, or any other pair inside `f`. Now suppose your SE contains only the origin, i.e., it is described by `S = {(0, 0)}`, so the only `s` in `S` is `(0, 0)`. If it also wasn't clear before, a flat SE is always a set of displacements. So, you see, you have a single displacement of `(0, 0)`. This means that any point `x`, `x + s = x`, thus you take `min(x + s) = min(x)` for erosion (the same for dilation, using `max`). This gives your original `f`, always.

Mathematical Morphology is not concerned on how specific libraries implement the operators, so there might be confusing situations after reading the description above.

Comment: and one more question, your explanation matched to gray scale morphology image, how about binary image? (only black and white)

Comment: For the binary case, those equations are usually presented in the form of intersection/union. But, actually, these ones can be applied just fine to binary images after you assign a value to the intensity white (1 for example) and another one to the intensity black (0 for example). Try applying these equations to such binary image and see what you get (exactly what you would expect with a erosion/dilation). If you experiment with that, and there is still some doubt, try making a simple illustration to show what you didn't understand.